# Stan: Local scopes in functions

Tags: scope, rstan

I am fairly new to Stan and have gone through the [manual (version 2.23)](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/reference-manual/index.html). What was new to me was that variable hiding is not allowed: you can not use a local variable (e.g. in a for-loop) that has been defined globally (i.e. outside the for-loop) ([chapter 7.9, Local Variable Declarations](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/reference-manual/statement-blocks-and-local-variable-declarations.html)).

Is the same true for user-defined functions? I.e., can you declare variables in user-defined functions that have the same name as other variables, that have been declared outside the function? In our case, we have

```
functions{
real[] my_function (x) {
    real init[K*2] = some_declaration_involving_x
    return(some_other_value_involving_init[])
  }
}

transformed data {
  real init[K*6] = some_other_declaration; // initial values
}

transformed parameters {
  yet_another_variable = my_function(some_variable)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's easy enough to test:

```
functions {
  int fun() {
    int N = 1;
    return N;
  }
}

model {
  real N = 2;
  print(fun(), N);
}
```